# Show that $\sin 3 \theta = 3\cos^2\theta \sin\theta - \sin^3\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

Use the de Moivre's formula to derive the following trigonometric identities

$$\sin 3 \theta = 3\cos^2\theta \sin\theta - \sin^3\theta$$

Comment: Well, use it.${}$

Answer (score 1):

One has: $$e^{3i\theta}=\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^3.$$
Therefore, taking the imaginary part and using the binomial theorem, one gets: $$\sin(3\theta)=\textrm{Im}\left((\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^3\right)=3\cos^2(\theta)\sin(\theta)-\sin^3(\theta).$$

Answer (score 0):

By De-Moivre's theorem We have,
$$\sin 3\theta+ i \cos 3\theta=(\sin \theta + i \cos \theta)^3=(\sin^3\theta-3\cos^2\theta \sin\theta)+i(3\sin^2 \theta \cos \theta+\cos ^3 \theta)$$

Now compairing real and complex part we have,
$$\sin 3\theta=\sin^3\theta-3\cos^2\theta \sin\theta$$ Proved.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially re-deriving De-moivre's theorem by using euler's formula.

We have that $$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x) \implies \sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i} \implies\sin(3x)=\frac{e^{3ix}-e^{-3ix}}{2i}=\frac{(e^{ix})^3-(e^{-ix})^3}{2i}.$$

Now, we use the difference of two cubes to obtain:

$$\frac{(e^{ix})^3-(e^{-ix})^3}{2i}=\frac{(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})(e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix}+1)}{2i}.$$

If you expand this, and notice that $$\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$

you will get exactly the desired result.